# e2image restore file system metadata

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, filesystems, ext4, virtual-disk

I'm trying to recreate file system metadata on a virtual disk. I can save this metadata using e2image, and the e2image man page tells me I can use `e2image -I` to restore the file system. Unfortunately, the man page doesn't provide any information on how to use this argument. I've tried the following (command results indented for easier reading):

```
msk $ e2image /dev/nbd1 -I test.qcow2
  e2image 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
  e2image: Wrong magic number for Ext2 Image Header while trying to open test.qcow2
msk $ sudo e2image /dev/nbd1 -I test.qcow2
  e2image 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
  e2image: Wrong magic number for Ext2 Image Header while trying to open test.qcow2
msk $ sudo e2image test.qcow2 -I /dev/nbd1
  e2image 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
  e2image: Wrong magic number for Ext2 Image Header while trying to open /dev/nbd1
```

My filesystem is in fact ext4, however the man page says the following:

```
The e2image program will save critical ext2, ext3, or ext4
```

I used the following command to create the image:

```
sudo e2image -Q /dev/mapper/nbd0p1 test.qcow2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

e2image supports three different formats; by default, it creates a "normal" custom e2image file format.  With -r it creates a large sparse file with metadata at proper offsets, and with -Q it creates a qcow2 format file.  (The -Q option was added somewhat recently to make large filesystem images more portable).

Although it's not at all clear from the manpage, the -I option is only valid for a "normal" e2image file format - i.e. an image created without -r or -Q.

Since you have a qcow2 image, you can use qemu-img to write it back out onto a block device:

```
# qemu-img convert -O raw test.qcow2 /dev/nbd1
```

***However***, you should be aware that your e2image-generated image contains *metadata only*, i.e. no file data at all.   You'll be writing out metadata which points to various blocks on /dev/nbd1 for file data, and files will therefore contain whatever data was previously in those blocks on /dev/nbd1.

So I've told you how to do it, but please be sure it's actually what you want to do!

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. I did come to this conclusion about metadata after doing some reading about file systems. And thanks for the clarification re: command-line switches.

Comment: In fact, for the record, file metadata is something I don't really want to keep, because I wanted to replace my files in the partition without consideration for their address on the device. So in conclusion, e2image is not really the tool I want to use. Thanks again for a clear answer, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to restore a QCOW2 image created using `e2image -Q` using `e2image -r`.  For example:

```
# e2image -Q /dev/sdb1 image.qcow2
# e2image -r image.qcow2 /dev/sdb2
```

Note that I tested this with version `1.42.12` of e2fsprogs.

As of `>= 1.42.9`, `e2image` also supports the `-a` flag which allows you to include filesystem data in addition to metadata:

```
# e2image -Qa /dev/sdb1 image-full.qcow2
# e2image -r image-full.qcow2 /dev/sdb2
```

I verified that in this case `e2image -r` writes only the allocated blocks back to the target, whereas `qemu-img convert` appears to write the entire logical filesystem.  That can save a lot of I/O for partially utilized filesystems.